# Classical control of an entire sub-circuit in cirq

Tags: circuit-construction, cirq

I would like to evolve a quantum state through an entire sub-circuit in my circuit based on classical control. I am aware of the current state of classical control in cirq (https://quantumai.google/cirq/build/classical_control) but this only deals with fundamental operations. Suppose I wanted to treat the sub-circuit as an atomic structure, which will be fully evolved or not evolved at all based on the classical condition, is it possible to achieve that?

In qiskit I could to the following:

```py
with circuit.if_test((c_reg, 0b110)):
        circuit.x(0)
        circuit.z(1)
```

I could add any number of circuit operations inside the `with` context and it will be treated as an atomic unit. I could not find a way to convert a `cirq.Circuit` into `cirq.Operation` either, I am not entirely sure if that would achieve my goal, but it was worth a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could not find a way to convert a cirq.Circuit into cirq.Operation either, I am not entirely sure if that would achieve my goal, but it was worth a shot.

You might be looking for the [CircuitOperation](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq/CircuitOperation) class.  It actually has the [with_classical_controls](https://quantumai.google/reference/python/cirq/CircuitOperation#with_classical_controls) method which should do what you need.